# populating dropdown with PDO::FETCH_ASSOC returns bool(false)

Tags: php, sql

i'm trying to populating dropdowns in PHP, but after the dropdown it returns bool(false)

start.php

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=hospital','root','');

?>
```

this is for the data i'm going to use and for the dropdown for the output

```
require 'start.php';

$doctorsQuery = "
    SELECT 
        specialties.SID,
        specialties.name,
        doctors.firstname,
        doctors.lastname,
        doctors.middleinitial 
    FROM specialties
    LEFT JOIN doctors
    ON specialties.SID = doctors.SID";

 $doctors = $db->query($doctorsQuery);

?>
```

This is for the select option in the dropdown

```
<?php foreach($doctors->fetchAll() as $specialty): ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $specialty['SID']; ?>"><?php echo 
$specialty['name']; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I'm trying to view the data here but it shows bool(false)

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['specialty'])){
$doctorQuery = "
{doctorsQuery}
WHERE specialties.SID == :S_ID";

$doctor = $db->prepare($doctorQuery);
$doctor->execute(['S_ID' => $_GET['specialty']]);

    $selectedDoctor = $doctor->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    var_dump($selectedDoctor);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It likes you using prepare statement with named placeholders, try this:

```
$doctor->execute([':S_ID' => $_GET['specialty']]); // you forget ":"
```

And... i suggest you to check **row count** before **fetch**..

```
if ($doctor->rowCount() === 1) {
    $selectedDoctor = $doctor->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // so you will not get false

    // your logic
} else {
    // when S_ID not found

}
```

Comment: i tried what you said but it still returns bool(false)